# Rspec error when running first tests on a new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running my first test on a new app, and I am getting this error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core
2.14.4, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.13.1. Using bundle exec
may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I don't know what it means by "activated rspec-core 2.14.4. I don't remember doing anything like this.

I ran the test from the command line with:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Ruby -v: 2.0.0

Rails -v: 4.0.0

The test in question:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Skeleton App'" do
      visit root_url
      expect(page).to have_content('Skeleton App')
    end
  end
end
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.1.0.rc'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

/Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git
  revision: 6da38c4c1a565bbcc62ed9b84c2574537c6ebae2
  specs:
    database_cleaner (1.2.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails.git
  revision: 0dd45e59d3237b4c8f9efc215b46d9c07072a95e
  specs:
    spork-rails (4.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      spork (>= 1.0rc0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.1)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.0.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.15.2)
      timers (~> 1.1.0)
    childprocess (0.3.6)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.6)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (4.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    cucumber (1.3.9)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.0.2)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    devise (3.2.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    gherkin (2.12.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (2.2.3)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.1)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-rspec (2.5.0)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.11)
    guard-spork (1.5.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.3)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    jbuilder (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    json_pure (1.8.1)
    listen (2.2.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    multi_test (0.0.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rubyzip (1.1.0)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (4.0.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    selenium-webdriver (2.0.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.9)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    slop (3.4.6)
    spork (1.0.0rc4)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.0.1)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.0.1.0.rc)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.9)
  capybara (= 2.1.0)
  childprocess (= 0.3.6)
  coffee-rails (= 4.0.0)
  cucumber-rails (= 1.3.0)
  database_cleaner!
  devise
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.0)
  faker (= 1.1.2)
  growl (= 1.0.3)
  guard-rspec (= 2.5.0)
  guard-spork (= 1.5.0)
  jbuilder (= 1.0.2)
  jquery-rails (= 2.2.1)
  pg (= 0.15.1)
  rails (= 4.0.0)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rspec-rails (= 2.13.1)
  sass-rails (= 4.0.0)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.0.0)
  spork-rails!
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.7)
  turbolinks (= 1.1.1)
  uglifier (= 2.1.1)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.4)
```

Comment: Do you see a reference to `rspec-core 2.14.4` in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Do you see rspec-core 2.14.4 in `gem list -d rspec-core`?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Gemfile.lock file for multiple rspec-core dependencies. It's likely one of your included gems has locked a dependency that is inconsistent with the version you're locking to.

Paste in your Gemfile.lock file here for more help.

A reasonable solution would be to use an operator in your gemfile that allows for less restrictive version locking. The pessimistic operator (`gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.13') will allow versions of rspec-rails >= 2.13 and < 3. More info here: http://techiferous.com/2011/05/sanely-updating-your-gems/

Answer (score 1):

try this: In your Gemfile specify:

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.14"
  #other gems for development and test only
end
```

then in the shell cd to your application directory and run

```
bundle install
```

Let me know if this works or if i missed something.

Comment: the change you suggested did not work, I am now getting an error when I run bundle install (I added Gemfile.lock above): Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-core":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rspec-core (2.13.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (~> 2.14) ruby depends on
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0) ruby

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what was causing this error, but I removed all rspec related (actually all testing related) gems from Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, added them back, and ran `bundle install` again, and so far it seems to be working.

Comment: strange thing. Did something change in your Gemfile or Gemfile.lock by removing and adding those gems?

Comment: Not that I can tell, very strange